# lost control in LeaderBoard - GameCenter

Tags: iphone, gamekit, game-center, leaderboard

I want to add Game center for my project but now I get some stuck and can't find any solution for my problem by Google :(
When I call method showleaderboard in my project, leaderboard appear and success to load my score in gamecenter but it don't receive touch (this screen look like freeze).
This is my code:

```
-(void) ShowLeaderBoardCategory:(NSString *)my_category
 {
GKLeaderboardViewController * leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if(leaderboardController != nil)
{
    leaderboardController.category = my_category;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = mySubView;
    [mySubView presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
    [glView addSubview:mySubView.view];

}
[leaderboardController release];

 }
-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
 {

[mySubView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[mySubView release];
[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[viewController release];

 }
```

mySubView is interface I define:

```
@interface MyUIView : UIViewController<GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
 ......
```

and used it:

```
MyUIView *mySubView;
```

Please, tell me what wrong in my code? :((
What reason can there be to stop receiving cocos2d events?
Thanks for reading and hope your hint.

Answer (score 0):

[viewController.view.**superview** removeFromSuperview];

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your removal method: where viewController refers to the leaderboard:

```
[mySubView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //this removes the modally presnted leaderboard.
[mySubView  removeFromSuperview]; //this should show up the glView
```